# TSQL query with aggregated data

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a query that returns the min, max, avg and total for two different products. The client however wants the min, max, avg and total combined for both products. However I have an undesired result returned when I try to sum the two products and try to aggregate the date.

The following SQL query returns the individual data for both product:

```
SELECT 
   CONVERT(date, DateTimeNow) AS Date,
   MIN(FT1) AS Minimum1 , 
   MAX(FT1) AS Maximum1, 
   AVG(FT1) AS Average1, 
   MAX(FQ1) AS Total1,
   MIN(FT2) AS Minimum2, 
   MAX(FT2) AS Maximum2, 
   AVG(FT2) AS Average2, 
   MAX(FQ2) AS Total2
FROM Data
GROUP BY CONVERT(date, DateTimeNow)
ORDER BY CONVERT(date, DateTimeNow);
```

I then modified the query to the following:

```
SELECT 
    CONVERT(date, DateTimeNow) AS Date,
    MIN(FT1+FT2) AS Minimum , 
    MAX(FT1+FT2) AS Maximum, 
    AVG(FT1+FT2) AS Average, 
    MAX(FQ1+FT2) AS Total
FROM Data
GROUP BY CONVERT(date, DateTimeNow)
ORDER BY CONVERT(date, DateTimeNow);
```

However when I run the second query the results don't add up. As an example Minimum does not add up to the first query Minimum1 + Minimum2

Comment: Need some sample data and expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand that you are storing each product in a different column in the same table. The logic to compute the combined minimum, average and maximum might be as follows :

```
SELECT 
    CONVERT(date, DateTimeNow) AS Date,
    CASE WHEN MIN(FT1) < MIN(FT2) THEN MIN(FT1) ELSE MIN(FT2) END AS Minimum, 
    CASE WHEN MAX(FT1) > MAX(FT2) THEN MAX(FT1) ELSE MAX(FT2) END AS Maximum, 
    ( AVG(FT1) + AVG(FT2) ) / 2 AS Average,
    SUM(FT1) + SUM(FT2) AS Total
FROM Data
GROUP BY CONVERT(date, DateTimeNow)
ORDER BY CONVERT(date, DateTimeNow);
```

Meaning :

- minimum is the lowest value between the minimum of product 1 and the minimum of product 2
- maximum is the highest value between the maximum of product 1 and the maximum of product 2
- average is the average of the average of product 1 and the average of product 2
- total is the sum of both queries

You can adapt these rules as needed according to your requiremens (which you did not fully specified).

Comment: Thanks for this, although not entirely what I was after but this helped to steer me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to everyone for your input. Below was the correct query I was after:

```
SELECT 
    CONVERT(date, DateTimeNow) AS Date, MIN(FT1) + MIN(FT2) AS Minimum, 
    MAX(FT1) + MAX(FT2) AS Maximum,
    AVG(FT1) + AVG(FT2) / 2 AS Average,
    MAX(FQ1) + MAX(FQ2) AS Total1
FROM #rawData
GROUP BY CONVERT(date, DateTimeNow)
ORDER BY CONVERT(date, DateTimeNow);
```

Comment: You are missing parens around the average computation : `AVG(FT1) + AVG(FT2) / 2 AS Average` shoud be `(AVG(FT1) + AVG(FT2)) / 2 AS Average`

Answer (score 1):

I would strongly suggest:

```
SELECT CONVERT(date, DateTimeNow) AS Date,
       MIN(v.FT) AS Minimum , 
       MAX(v.FT) AS Maximum, 
       AVG(v.FT) AS Average, 
       MAX(v.FQ1) AS Total
FROM Data CROSS APPLY
     (VALUES (FT1, FQ1), (FT2, FQ2)) as v(FT, FQ)
GROUP BY CONVERT(date, DateTimeNow)
ORDER BY CONVERT(date, DateTimeNow);
```

In particular, this should handle `NULL` values correctly.  The average of two values is not necessarily the average of the averages of the two values.

Answer (score 0):

The "FROM" Clause does the adding by including both records you want to do the operations against.    Your Date logic is not doing anything - it is grabbing all records for all days and then "falsely" putting today's date always.

```
SELECT CONVERT(date, DateTimeNow) AS Date, MIN(FT) AS Minimum , MAX(FT) AS Maximum, AVG(FT) AS Average, SUM(FT) AS Total, COUNT(FT) as NumOfRecs
FROM Data
WHERE ProductName IN ('FTName1','FTName2')
GROUP BY CONVERT(date, DateTimeNow)
ORDER BY CONVERT(date, DateTimeNow);
```